# Can we run another instance of application on cloud?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, multiprocessing, cloud-hosting

How can we run multiple instance of our application on cloud?

I've to perform some task which may take long time to execute, so I would like to perform all these task to out of context or on another instance so application will run fine without affecting user interface.

Is there any other way to archive mentioned task?

Answer (score 0):

You could create another application specifically designed to perform the task. Note however that performing long running background tasks in ASP.NET applications is bad design and should be avoided. Phil Haack wrote a [`nice article`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) on this topic.

So you could create a Windows Service that will perform those long running tasks or simply a console application that could be scheduled to run at regular intervals using the Windows Scheduler.

Comment: How can i call that service or console application on a specific event?

Comment: You could host a Web API inside the Windows Service. Then it would be as simple as sending an HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Windows Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/) worker roles. They are cloud based and can perform [long running tasks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/morebits/archive/2011/01/01/building-windows-azure-service-part5-worker-role-background-tasks-handler.aspx). Can also use Web role to host the UI